# Pick Balls with Unequal Probabilities

Tags: markov-chains, markov-process, conditional-probability, poisson-process

There are some balls with 4 different colors in a black box.
The ratio of A color ball is 10%, B is 20%, C is 30% and D is 40%.

The rule of this game is that you randomly pick one ball and mark the color of this ball then throw it back to the box.

The Question is:
When you already have marked 2 different color balls, what is the probability of that the next time you pick one ball is the same color with the previous 2 colors (P22), and is different with previous 2 colors (P23).

Here is what I thought:
Use Markov matrix to solve the problem, the states are AB AC AD BC BD CD ABC ABD BCD ACD, so we can build a $10 * 10$ matrix T: $$AB->AB = 0.3, AB->AC=0.0 ... AB->ABC=0.3, AB->ABD=0.4$$ etc.

calc:
   $$\lim_{n\to\infty} {T}^n$$
I am not sure this method is correct.

Is this a Poisson Process?

Comment: Please clarify the question sentence. Did you mean that the ball you are picking has the **either** the same color as the two previous ones **or** a different color than the two previously found balls?

Comment: Actually there are two  probabilities I want to calculate. The one (P22) is that  the probability of that the next time you pick one ball is the same color with the previous 2 colors, the other(P23) is that the probability of that the next time you pick one ball is different with previous 2 colors. Sorry for the misunderstanding.